# What is the equivalent of html break when passed to javascript

Tags: javascript, html, newline

I am passing strings from HTML to Javascript

```
<textarea ></textarea>
```

If user press 'ENTER' inside the textarea...

for example

```
hello there
I hit the enter key
```

Once this strings were submitted to javascript, how would it look like?

is it something like this?

```
pass_character = "hello there \n I hit the enter key";
```

but '\n' seems wrong. I made a test that

```
text = pass_character.split(' ');
if(text[i] == '\n')
       do something
```

I want to know the equivalent of line break or 'enter' when it is already passed to javascript, so I can manage the text in the future code.

Comment: Never leave off braces on an if statement, the extra line you gain isn't worth the confusion later.

Comment: To see the representation of line break in a particular system, just print out the characters of a string containing a line break, using e.g. the `charCodeAt()` method.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the equivalent code will be a line break, but in your example there shouldn't be spaces between `\n`.

Answer (score 1):

I would use `\r\n` when adding text into a textarea, since it preserves formatting and doesn't render HTML entities. If you plan to use that text as HTML you may need to convert these to line breaks. Using `\n` will work for Unix based systems, but you may or may not get issues with it in old versions of IE. More importantly - when a user copies the text out and pastes it the original formatting will also be preserved and you may need to consider whether to conditionally apply line breaks as carriage returns and/or line feeds.

http://jsfiddle.net/NgcuF/1/

Answer (score 0):

By the HTML spec, a [line break](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/text.html#line-breaks) can be a line feed (LF), a carriage return (CR), or a CR LF pair. This means that from the JavaScript perspective, an HTML line feed may be `'\n'` or `'\r'` or `'\r\n'`, depending on implementation.

When a form containing a textarea is submitted, the browser is required to canonicalize line breaks to CR LF, which is the Internet convention on them. And this is what browsers do. But they do not need to do so internally for element content, only when preparing form data for submission.